# Event fired when item is added to ListView?

Tags: wpf

I have this XAML:

```
<ListView Name="NameListView"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          Grid.Column="1">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                        <Binding Path="First" />
                        <Binding Path="Last" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

and an `ObservableCollection<Name>` called "names" binded to the ListView in my code-behind. When a new new name is added to the collection, I want the ListView to change the background color of that newly added name. How do I go about doing it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've fixed the code formatting in the question for you. Please take a moment to read the handy **How to Format** box to the right of the Ask a Question area, and [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area. (There's also a preview box shown under the Ask a Question box where you can preview your question.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can subscribe to the ItemsChanged event on your listbox.Items property. This is a little tricky because you have to cast it first. The code to subscribe would look like this:

```
((INotifyCollectionChanged)MainListBox.Items).CollectionChanged +=  ListBox_CollectionChanged;
```

And then inside that event you can get to your item with code like this:

```
private void ListBox_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems.Count > 0)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                var newListItem = MainListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(e.NewItems[0]) as Control;
                if (newListItem != null)
                {
                    newListItem.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
                }
            }, DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. It's not a ListBox but a ListView 2. It's the Background not the foreground 3. I cannot see such an event anywhere on either control.

Comment: Modified my code above to make it more clear. Also this should work with any ItemsControl (ListBox or ListView).

Comment: I'm quite sure this ain't gonna work out. For one thing casting to ListItem is never going to work because ListItem is a Documents control which has nothing to with with either ListBox or ListView.

Comment: Yea I meant to say ListBoxItem - but in any case it just needs to be a control. The code above does work I just ran it to make sure. I agree if he is going to use MVVM he should add the property to his ViewModel. However, if he doesn't want to use MVVM this code will work and he won't have to set up a ViewModel and everything.

Comment: I was able to use your solution in my project. And I wish we were using MVVM, but everything is being done in code-behind of the control.

Comment: Why use `Dispatcher`? Does this event get fired in another thread?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the background of a ListViewItem directly is not a good idea because by default a ListView is virtualizing (which is good), that means the controls that make up the items get disposed when scrolled out of view. The easiest way to do this is that i can think of is having a property in your data-object which indicates the New-state, then you can trigger on it.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsNew}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

You then can use any logic you want to set that value to false again if you do not consider it new anymore.