# WPF: Raise an Event when Item is added in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, events, listview

I am working on WPF and I am using a ListView, and I need to fire an event when an item is added to it. I have tried this:

```
var dependencyPropertyDescriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, typeof(ListView));
        if (dependencyPropertyDescriptor != null)
        {
               dependencyPropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged(this, ItemsSourcePropertyChangedCallback);
        }
```

.....

```
 private void ItemsSourcePropertyChangedCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         RaiseItemsSourcePropertyChangedEvent();
    }
```

But It seems to be working only when the entire collection is changed, I have read this post: [event-fired-when-item-is-added-to-listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904519/event-fired-when-item-is-added-to-listview), but the best answer applies for a listBox only. I tried to change the code to ListView but I wasnt able to do that.

I hope You can help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the comments of answer to the question you post you will find "Modified my code above to make it more clear. Also this should work with any ItemsControl (ListBox or ListView)."  - What problem are you having in particular?

Comment: @Slugart Thank you for your reply, the problem I having is that the method `BeginInvoke` does not accept the declaration as the example. It says that `DispatcherPriority` does not exist

Answer (score 66, accepted):

*Note this only works for a WPF Listview!*

After some research I have found the answer to my question and It's really easy:

```
public MyControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ((INotifyCollectionChanged)listView.Items).CollectionChanged +=  ListView_CollectionChanged;
}

private void ListView_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)     
{
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
      // scroll the new item into view   
      listView.ScrollIntoView(e.NewItems[0]);
    }
}
```

Actually, the `NotifyCollectionChangedAction` enum allows your program to inform you about any change such as: Add, Move, Replace, Remove and Reset.

Comment: This does not work for me.  I get Unable to cast object of type 'ListViewItemCollection' to type 'System.Collections.Specialized.INotifyCollectionChanged'.

Comment: For anyone else who is curious, `ListView.Items` is of type `ItemsCollection`. This inherits from `CollectionView` which implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Looking at MSDN, this was true for .NET 3.0 - 4.6. @Arvo `ListViewItemCollection` only implements `IList, ICollection, IEnumerable` and doesn't inherit from anything, hence your exception.

Comment: Works with WPF Listbox too. If a observablecollection<string> is bound, the the first occurrence will be brought into View! So if the same value can occur multiple times, use a class with one property to bind (observablecollection<myclass>) and set the DisplayMemberPath accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

*Note: This solution was meant for a WinForms ListView.*

In my case I ended up coming to a fork in the road with 2 choices...

**(1)** Create a custom ListView control that inherits a ListView's class.  Then add a new event to be raised when any item is added, deleted, or ListView is cleared.  This path seemed really messy and long.  Not to mention the other big issue that I would need to replace all my original ListViews with the newly created Custom ListView control.  So I passed on this!

---

**(2)** With every add, delete, or clear call to the listview I also called another function simulating the CollectionChanged event.

**Create the new event like function...**

```
private void myListViewControl_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //The projects ListView has been changed
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            MessageBox.Show("An Item Has Been Added To The ListView!");
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
            MessageBox.Show("The ListView Has Been Cleared!");
            break;
    }
}
```

**Add an item to the ListView elsewhere...**

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem("ListViewItem 1");
lvi.SubItems.Add("My Subitem 1");
myListViewControl.Items.Add(lvi);
myListViewControl_CollectionChanged(myListViewControl, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, lvi, lvi.Index));
```

**Clear the ListView elsewhere...**

```
myListViewControl.Items.Clear();
myListViewControl_CollectionChanged(myListViewControl, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
```

Comment: It's pretty odd that Dante's solution doesn't work for you, especially when your work-around involves... `INotifyCollectionChanged`. `((INotifyCollectionChanged)MyList.Items).CollectionChanged += MyListChanged` worked for me. Are you sure you put the parenthesis in the right places?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with WPF, I don't use that, I'm using WinForms.  Not sure, all I know is that all namespaces are accounted for and all references work perfect with those objects/types.  I don't even really get how you could cast a collection of listView.Items to INotifyCollectionChanged (Not saying it can't be done, I just don't get it).  Everything else looks good except that part.  I'm more then willing to try something out if you tell me.  But as it stands my VS 2010 says no!  ;)

Comment: WinForms and WPF are two totally different beasts; a WinForms `ListView` has **nothing** to do with a WPF `ListView`! The WPF `ListViewItemCollection` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`; this allows WPF's powerful data binding capabilities to detect changes in the list and [almost] *automagically* keep everything up-to-date. You should consider leaving WinForms behind and trying out WPF - once you get the hang of it, you'll never look back! :)

Comment: Thanks!  Noted.  I edited Dante's answer for a few reasons (adding a note at the top for pure c# developers such as me).  As soon as the edit is accepted it gets a vote up from me.  I'll try WPF soon!  ;)  I need to move from 2010 to 2013 too.  hehe

Comment: No problem, except the question is already tagged [tag:wpf]... (not my downvote)

Comment: Ha!  no worries, everyone has opinions. ;)  I just added all that and left my answer to help others out.  When I was looking for a solution like this for my needs I was lead here.  So I figured why not try to help the next guy out.  Maybe someone will benefit from it.