# Triggering button visibility based on position in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ListView with multiple items.  The ListViewItems is a template that contains details about the item from the ObservableCollection and a Button.

My goal is for the button to only be visible on the very last ListViewItem.  To that end I implemented a converter and bound it to the Button's visibility, which checks ListViewItem's index vs the ListView's count and returns Visibility.Visible or Visibility.Collapsed.

This works fine when the page first loads, but when I add additional items to the ListView, it doesn't update the existing ListViewItems, it only runs the Converter for the new Items.

Is there a nice xaml (MVVM friendly) way to trigger it to run the Binding?

My XAML:

```
        <ListView x:Name="lstBox" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" Background="Yellow" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Firstname}" />
                    <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.AddPersonCommand}" Content="Add Person" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Converter={StaticResource IsLastItemToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

My Converter:

```
    public class IsLastItemToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ListViewItem item = value as ListViewItem;
        ListView ListView = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item) as ListView;
        int index = ListView.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item);
        if (index == ListView.Items.Count - 1)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you put a single button under the listview (over the last item maybe) instead?

Comment: I believe you have to implement the `ConvertBack` and set the Binding Mode to `TwoWay`

Comment: The single button would be my preferred solution, but the requirement I was given is to do it this way.

Comment: How would I implement the ConvertBack?   The value of the Convert is the ListViewItem and the return is Visibility.  There's no way to convert Visibility back to a ListViewItem...

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to pass the item as a command parameter.

```
<ListView x:Name="lstBox"
                  Background="Yellow"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                        <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}},
                                                  Path=DataContext.AddPersonCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                Content="Add Person"
                                Visibility="{Binding IsEnabled,
                                                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                                     Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

The CanExecute of the command should return true only when the item is last in the collection. Something like this:

```
  private bool CanAddPerson(object arg)
    {

        return _people.Last().Equals(arg);
    }
```

Comment: But that's dependent on the item being the last in the underlying collection?   The requirement is that its the last item in the ListView regardless of the position in the collection, eg - if the ListView were put through some or other sorting?

Answer (score 0):

The `ObservableCollection` should contain items of a ViewModel Type (like Person or whatever you want to call it). That viewmodel should contain a `Visibility` value for each of the items button and you change your converter to a `BoolToVisibilityConverter`.

In this sollution you just have to update the visibility of items when you change the collection. You have an event where you can do this. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884031/wpf-raise-an-event-when-item-is-added-in-listview) for more details about the collection changed event.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This also sounds like it would be dependent on the order in the underlying collection rather than the order in the ListView?   Besides, I'm trying to stay away from modifying the ViewModel.

Comment: The order of the collection is the order of the Lisview.. That's what the view model is there for. Providing a presentation logic layer. You asked for a MVVM way to do it. If you don't want to modify your VM than you're not looking for a MVVM friendly way of doing that ;)

Comment: The project head wants the view model completely uncoupled from the form logic.  Acceptable solutions at this point is either entirely in xaml, or a combination of converters or a small amount of code behind for the form.

Comment: And while some changes to the view model might end up necessary that's somebody else's responsibility and will require proposing changes which is a whole lot of red tape I'd like to avoid.  A lot of the proposed solutions have been stuff that I'd thought of already but would like to leave as a last resort if it really isn't possible.  I'm willing to replace the converter with a data trigger but ended up with the same situation, not being able to get the trigger to fire on existing buttons.