# Implementing CollectionChanged Handler in XAML with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events, user-interface, event-handling

I used the solution located at [stackoverflow:event-fired-when-item-is-added-to-listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904519/event-fired-when-item-is-added-to-listview) to utilize interface INotifyCollectionChanged in CodeBehind.  Is there a way to add this EventHandler within the XAML?

Essentially, I want this line defined in XML:

```cs
((INotifyCollectionChanged)lbFiles.Items).CollectionChanged += lbFiles_SelectionChanged;
```

Comment: Are you implementing your own GUI element? Typically, you bind an ItemsSource property of an element to an observable collection and things just light up.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be creating the `CollectionChanged` event on the collection that is bound to your ListBox/ListView etc, accessing controls derictly from code behind is not the WPF way to do things.

Example:

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="340" Width="480" Name="UI" >
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyProperty}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _myProperty = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyProperty.CollectionChanged += MyProperty_CollectionChanged;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> MyProperty
    {
        get { return _myProperty; }
        set { _myProperty = value; }
    }

    void MyProperty_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Collection Changed
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to troubleshoot Bindings in any way as I learn proper syntax?  I have modified my code, but I assume the event handler is being automatically added because the CollectionChanged event is no longer firing.

Comment: Is there something I am missing in this example?  I know the bindings must be working because I change the getter on my Observable collection to a static list of strings, and the event handler is now firing.  But the ListBox elements are not updating. When I debug, the ItemsSource Property is not equal what the UI is displaying, ie: ListBox is always blank, even if there are >= 1 elements in the Property defined by ItemsSource, which I guarantee is bound correctly.

Comment: I've posted a more conceete question here: [ObservableCollection<T> WPF Binding Display Not Updating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404495/observablecollectiont-wpf-binding-display-not-updating)