# model with changes in observable collection item details not updating DataGrid View in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a selected tree view item which has an ObservableCollection of models(employee) and when an item/employee is selected from tree , i am displaying the employee details like id(textblock),name(textblock), and promotion details (in a DataGrid  which is an observable collection of another model called "PromotionHistory") and it displays the details correctly.

```
<TreeView x:Name="EmployeesDataTree" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}"/>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=EmployeesDataTree, Path=SelectedItem.EmployeePromotionDetails}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee Promotion Id" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee NewTitle" Binding="{Binding NewTitle}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee Location " Binding="{Binding Location}" />
            .... 
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Upon a button("UpdateLocation") click when i change the Location name cell value in the PromotionHistory datagrid in my viewmodel through code, the changes are not reflecting back to UI though my observablecollection item details have been successfully updated.

```
foreach (var item in (SelectedEmployeeItem as EmployeeModel).EmployeePromotionDetails)
{
     // condition which hits service and verify if the location name is      up to date by searching with id and updates.
    if(condition)
    {
        item.Name = "New Location";
    }
}
```

After some research on this site, I found that my problem is  ObservableCollection itself (such as adding/removing items) didn't change but only the items INSIDE that collection. But i couldn't get the ui/view updated with the changes.

Comment: The items need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Your research should have turned up that fact. Naturally you can't bear the thought of sharing the setter code for `item.Name` (this is SO, after all), but it doesn't raise `PropertyChanged`, does it? There are very few ways to get this wrong, and that's pretty much all of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ObservableCollection<T> WPF Binding Display Not Updating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404495/observablecollectiont-wpf-binding-display-not-updating)

Comment: Try adding `Mode=TwoWay` so that your view can get updated when the source changes. E.g. `Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"` and same for `NewTitle` as well as `Location`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your `item` is Type of class `PromotionHistory` your class needs to implement the following:

```
public class PromotionHistory : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name {
        get { return _name; }
        set {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The `PropertyChanged` event is updating your UI. The ObservableCollection only has effects in adding or removing items through `CollectionChanged` event, which is independenend from changed item properties.

Answer (score 0):

Does each item implement INotifyPropertyChanged? If not that is your issue. The ObservableCollection needs to be informed of changes and the INotifyPropertyChanged interface does this.